# How to quickly scroll to top in android?

Tags: applications

In iOS, it's possible to tap on the status bar to scroll to top and automatically go to the beginning of a list. Is there such feature in android as well? I am looking for a way to go to the beginning of a large list without needing to tediously swiping my finger down repeatedly thousands of times.